# Why is a unique pointer not movable inside a lambda if it's a captured value?

Tags: c++, c++17

The following code does not compile:

```
struct S{};

void foo(std::unique_ptr<S> ptr)
{
    auto l = [p = std::move(ptr)]()
    {
        auto p2 = std::move(p);
    };
    l();
}
```

The reason is that `std::move(p)` returns an lvalue reference and hence the compiler tries to call the copy constructor, which is deleted. Why does `move` return an lvalue reference here?

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/UNHVnx) is a full sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mark the lambda `mutable`, otherwise its captures are `const`. As in

```
auto l = [p = std::move(ptr)]() mutable { ... };
```

Comment: That explains it. I was wondering if the captures are const but intellisense told me `p` is `std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<S>&>::type` which confused me. Thanks.

Comment: @Timo Intellisense is *not* the compiler. It tries to help by partially compiling the code and guessing. It may be helpful, sometimes, but never treat it as a source of truth - it very much *is not*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yeah I know that, but since the compiler didn't give me much of an answer (except that I try to call a deleted copy constructor) Intellisense was the closest source of information I had.

Comment: The argument to `foo` is by value. It should be `void foo(std::unique_ptr<S>& ptr)` to pass (and move)  the unique ptr into the lambda. Alternately, the move could be at the calling function.

Comment: @doug *"The argument to foo is by value."* So what? I don't see anything wrong with it. Passing by lvalue reference, on the other hand, would prevent you from passing in temporaries. It would also make the semantics of `foo` confusing (when you pass a varible to a function, you generally don't expect it to be moved from, unless you `std::move`'d it explicitly).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, I generally pass by reference when I move something later. But arguably, moving in the calling function is clearer and probably better.

Comment: Actually, the method `operator()` is const, not the captures